# Problema en una consulta me repite los códigos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta de 5 tablas los datos los muestra bien excepto los códigos y las fechas me las imprime repetidas lo que estoy haciendo es la hoja de vida de un equipo a los mantenimientos que se ha sometido algo asi como se muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el nombre de las tablas son: **orden_trabajo** seria el que mostraria el codigo y el detalle del mantenimiento que se le realizo junto con la fecha y tiene un campo no visible que se llama **Estado** que solo los que esten finalizados se deberian de mostrar, **solicitud_mante** el dato de esta no seria visible pero lo que hace es que en esta tabla se muestre solo los equipos que se les realizo un mantenimiento llamado **Correctivo Inmediato**, **matriz** se muestra la falla que tuvo y la posible solucion (son posibleas fallas en ciertos periodos), **listamaestra** esta tabla es la que contiene los equipos guardados, **ficha** en esta tabla se guarda la imagen del equipo con esas 5 tablas se sacan los datos para formar la hoja de vida de X equipo y esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT e.id_orden, a.id_list, b.Equipo, c.Imagen, d.falla, d.accion, d.frecuencia, e.detalle_mano, e.fecha_ini
FROM solicitud_mante AS a 
INNER JOIN listamaestra b ON b.id_list = a.id_list 
INNER JOIN ficha c ON c.id_list = a.id_list 
INNER JOIN matriz d ON d.id_list = a.id_list 
INNER JOIN orden_trabajo e ON e.id_soli = a.id_soli 
where e.Estado = 'Finalizado' and a.Tipo_mante='Correctivo Inmediato'
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a encontrar cual es el motivo que me repitan el código de orden y la fecha porque son registros distintos.

Comment: no entiendo el problema, parecen ser el mismo registro pero la falla y acción son diferentes, así como se ve interpreto que, es un mismo equipo que tuvo más de una corrección, registrado todo en un solo momento. Te refieres al código de equipo que es 02-02?

Comment: No, el código de orden y la fecha se repiten si te fijas se repite 64 como 6 veces y deben de ser distintos, el del equipo se repetirá porque  el mismo equipo puede tener distintas fallas y soluciones (afectara en algo por tantos INNER JOIN?)

Comment: me imagino que si, porqué no pruebas en hacer una consulta usando where para validar los id, sólo por probar? reemplazas los inner join con `where tablaB.id=tablaB.id`

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos reproducir el [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo